# Spring and middleware conflict?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, ruby-on-rails-5, google-oauth, rails-spring

I'm trying to add oauth2 with Google, following [these instructions](https://richonrails.com/articles/google-authentication-in-ruby-on-rails).

I'm receiving the following error message starting the server:

```
Exiting
You've tried to invoke Spring when it's already loaded (i.e. the Spring constant is defined).

This is probably because you generated binstubs with Spring 1.0, and you now have a Spring version > 1.0 on your system. To solve this, upgrade your bundle to the latest Spring version and then run `bundle exec spring binstub --all` to regenerate your binstubs. This is a one-time step necessary to upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1.

Here's the backtrace:

/Users/omonia/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/Users/omonia/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `block in load'
/Users/omonia/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'
/Users/omonia/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:287:in `load'
/Users/omonia/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-1.7.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/omonia/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require'
/Users/omonia/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `rescue in require'
/Users/omonia/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
/Users/omonia/Dropbox/MyApp/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
```

The related gems installed:

```
gem 'google-api-client', '0.9'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google_oauth2'
```

The following code is added to `config/initializers/omniauth.rb:`

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, 'my Google client id', 'my Google client secret', {client_options: {ssl: {ca_file: Rails.root.join("cacert.pem").to_s}}}
end
```

What is going on here? Following the error instructions doesn't change anything (Spring is of latest version 1.7.2 and running `bundle exec spring binstub --all` only returns "spring already present").

Comment: Did you upgrade `Spring` ?

Comment: Can you run first `bin/spring binstub --remove --all` and then `bundle exec spring binstub --all` ? make sure you upgrade spring befoe these all commands

Comment: I followed your steps now, but still the same error message. I should add that this is a new app, so barely no other disturbing code at all. Second thing to add: if I remove the code in the omniauth-initializer - I don't get any error anymore.

Comment: well what if you remove the whole spring? I think that should work. Just do `bin/spring binstub --remove --all` and remove the gem from `Gemfile` and run `bundle install` again. Ofcourse then restart the server.

Comment: I did as you said. The error disappeared, but another error about oauth appeared instead. After googling on that error [I learned](http://codegur.com/9366579/ruby-on-rails-could-not-find-matching-strategy-for-google-oauth2) that the `omniauth-google-oauth2` gem was spelled wrong (hypen instead of underscore). After fixing the second error I tried re-adding Spring and now the original error was gone as well. Thank you a thousand times @ArupRakshit for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: make a PR to fix the gem error. I remember I faced the same error 1 year back. :D

Answer (score 3):

Putting my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664754/spring-and-middleware-conflict?noredirect=1#comment64711069_38664754) as answer, because OP confirmed that it did help him. Follow the steps below to install the new Spring and resolve the issue:

- run this `bin/spring binstub --remove --all`
- remove the gem from Gemfile and run `bundle install`.
- Now add the `gem "spring", group: :development` in Gemfile, run `bundle install` and `bundle exec spring binstub --all` following [doc](https://github.com/rails/spring#setup). Now all should be fine.

Comment: I tried these steps but didn't work until I removed the `tmp/cache` and `vendor/bundle`

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue after code upgrade to new rails version, and the following comment helped me resolve it:

https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/610#issuecomment-578188439

Basically, disable spring loader in `bin/rails` stub, then run `rails s` until all the code issues are found and fixed, finally, enable spring back.

Answer (score 0):

Check **config/initializers/omniauth.rb** file and ensure that you have following content:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google, 'Client_Id', 'Client_Secret'
end
```

ensure that you exactly have the google provider (not github or facebook)

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me -

I ran this on console - `rake rails:update:bin`

then I ran `bundle exec spring binstub --all`

I don't guarantee that this would work for all.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I am not Ruby On Rails Expert, so correct me if I am doing anything wrong with the below steps.

The steps worked for me are below,

from MacOS Terminal run the following..

bin/spring binstub --remove --all

** Remove Your Cache folder under Vender (use Finder)

bundle install.

rails assets:precompile

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and after upgrading my ruby version from  2.6.1 to 2.7.1
and rails 5 to rails 6.

I read the discussion [Here](https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/610#issuecomment-578188439)
and after disable my ***loading spring code*** in **bin/rails**

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
end
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

TO:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../config/application', __dir__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

i got the error

> /home/humayun/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.7.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': cannot load such file -- thwait (LoadError)

and I fix this by adding the following gems to my gem file.

```sh
gem 'cmath'
gem 'scanf'
gem 'shell'
gem 'sync'
gem 'thwait'
gem 'e2mmap'
```

After this, my rails s is working fine and I move **bin/rails** to its original code.