# Error related with spring when trying to execute rails commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring

I have created a new rails application folder, which worked smoothly. Once within such folder, running any kind of rails command like `rails s` will prompt me:

```
You've tried to invoke Spring when it's already loaded (i.e. the Spring constant is defined).

This is probably because you generated binstubs with Spring 1.0, and you now have a Spring version > 1.0 on your system. To solve this, upgrade your bundle to the latest Spring version and then run `bundle exec spring binstub --all` to regenerate your binstubs. This is a one-time step necessary to upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1.
```

I currently have

```
spring -v
Spring version 2.1.0
```

I've tried the following, getting the same results. I also tried uninstalling spring and reinstalling.

```
 bundle exec spring binstub --all
* bin/rake: Spring already present
* bin/rails: Spring already present
```

Comment: Have you tried running `bundle exec spring binstub --all` ?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem to do any changes.

Comment: Some of the steps from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664754/spring-and-middleware-conflict might help

Comment: I've tried the indications in that post and kept not working. Somehow running `gem pristine --all` solves the issue, but not sure why

Comment: `gem pristine --all` left me with `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted @ apply2files - /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionmailbox-6.1.4/CHANGELOG.md`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Posting this as an answer after trying every other related solutions to finally find this hidden in a comment. Hope it helps someone in the future.

As for the why, the only reason I see on my side is upgrading from ubuntu (pop os) 20.04 to 20.10. Didn't do anything else between my two coding sessions.

> I've tried the indications in that post and kept not working. Somehow
> running `gem pristine --all` solves the issue, but not sure why –
> Gotey Jan 3 at 14:05

Comment: This only left me with an error. A new error, but an error nonetheless: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted @ apply2files - /Users/xxxxxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actionmailbox-6.1.4/CHANGELOG.md`

Comment: This worked for me, this command clean all gems for the current ruby version. And by the documentation, with "bundle pristine" the same occur only by gem on lockfile.  https://bundler.io/man/bundle-pristine.1.html#:~:text=Meanwhile%2C%20gem%20pristine%20%2D%2Dall,and%20instead%20run%20bundle%20pristine%20.

Answer (score 1):

It may happen when you've `require` something in your code which is not installed.

For instance, I've encountered this issue when I was imported `sentry-ruby` without installing actual gem. Check your dependencies and imports.

Comment: I had the same issue. In my case a missed `s` in the file name. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I removed the `spring` and `spring-watcher-listen` gems from the `Gemfile` and then uninstalled these 2 gems via the `bundle exec gem uninstall gemname` command.

I then discovered a new error when trying to run `rails s` which was about `MySQL`. Finally after fixing those errors I was able to do a successful `rails s`. I then added back the 2 gems, ran `bundle` and had no errors afterwards.