# You've tried to invoke Spring when it's already loaded (i.e. the Spring constant is defined)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

This is probably because you generated binstubs with Spring 1.0, and you now have a Spring version > 1.0 on your system. To solve this, upgrade your bundle to the latest Spring version and then run `bundle exec spring binstub --all` to regenerate your binstubs. This is a one-time step necessary to upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1.

Here's the backtrace:

/Users/m/Image-Classifier/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load' /Users/m/Image-Classifier/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in` <top (required)>'
/Users/m/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require' /Users/m/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.1/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in` require'
/Users/m/Image-Classifier/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>' /Users/m/Image-Classifier/bin/rails:3:in` load'
/Users/m/Image-Classifier/bin/rails:3:in `'

I try with [Spring and middleware conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38664754/spring-and-middleware-conflict) but don't worked

Comment: I have Mac OS Catalina

Comment: I ran `bundle update`. seemed to have fixed it.